# Dagger 2.10+: Inject dependency with activity context in Activities and Fragments

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have a class called `AlertManager` which requires `Activity` instance to show `Toast` and `AlertDialog`.

```
class AlertManager @Inject constructor(private val activity: Activity) {

    fun showToast(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Now, I want `AlertManager` as dependency in two activities `HomeActivity` & `ProductsActivity`. Currently I have created modules for each `Activity` like:

```
@Module
class HomeActivityModule {
    @Provides
    @ActivityContext
    fun provideAlertManager(activity: HomeActivity) = AlertManager(activity)
}
```

And

```
@Module
class ProductsActivityModule {
    @Provides
    @ActivityContext
    fun provideAlertManager(activity: ProductsActivity) = AlertManager(activity)
}
```

And binding them with Dagger like

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityProvider {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [HomeActivityModule::class])
    @ActivityContext
    abstract fun bindHomeActivity(): HomeActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ProductsActivityModule::class])
    @ActivityContext
    abstract fun bindProductsActivity(): ProductsActivity
}
```

Now my questions are:

**1)** How can I avoid creating modules for each activities and have common `ActivityModule` which I can bind with whatever `Activity` I want?

**2)** Let's say I have a fragment called `HomeFragment` inside `HomeActivity`, then how can I inject the same `AlertManager` instance of  `HomeActivity` inside the fragment?

I am stuck here since quite long and have tried to find a lot over internet but I am unable to find any blog or guide which can help me to achieve what I am looking for. If someone can point me in right direction, I'll be grateful.

Comment: There's a related [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/961)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) How can I avoid creating modules for each activities and have common ActivityModule which I can bind with whatever Activity I want?

You can have some sort of **AlertManagerModule** where you add generic activity.

```
@Provides
fun provideAlertManager(activity: Activity) = AlertManager(activity)
```

You still will have to make individual activity modules. One change you can make is:

```
@Module
abstract class HomeActivityModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun providesActivity(activity: HomeActivity) : Activity
}
```

And then you can add them to the ActivityProvider class:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityProvider {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [HomeActivityModule::class, AlertManagerModule::class])
    abstract fun bindHomeActivity(): HomeActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ProductsActivityModule::class, AlertManagerModule::class])
    abstract fun bindProductsActivity(): ProductsActivity
}
```

> 2) Let's say I have a fragment called HomeFragment inside HomeActivity, then how can I inject the same AlertManager instance of HomeActivity inside the fragment?

Since you're using **DaggerActivity** and most likely using **DaggerFragment**, the fragment instantiated in the **HomeFragment** can directly get the AlertManager by simply using the @Inject annotation in the fragment provided you add in the **HomeActivityModule**:

```
 @Module
 abstract class HomeActivityModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun providesActivity(activity: HomeActivity) : Activity

    @FragmentScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun providesHomeFragment() : HomeFragment;
}
```

Comment: Your first solution worked and I am able to bind the instance that way. There's still need to create separate modules, but your suggested way is much better. However, I am not able to inject `AlertManager` in fragment. I still get:
`android.app.Activity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method`.

Comment: @SandipSoni Instead of installing the `@ContributesAndroidInjector HomeFragment` directly in your AppComponent, install it in the same array of modules as `[HomeActivityModule::class, AlertManagerModule::class]`. This means that your subcomponent of `HomeFragment` is under the subcomponent of `HomeActivity`. Also make sure your `HomeActivity` extends `DaggerActivity`.

Comment: @SandipSoni I see where the problem is. You have to add HomeFragment ContributesAndroidInjector not in a standalone appmodule but inside the HomeActivityModule.

Comment: Thanks guys, it finally worked. I am not happy with the part where I still have to create module for each activity, but seems like that's the only way for now and hence accepting this answer. Thanks again :)